# docker-compose run command cannot find gem after running bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rspec, docker-compose, bundler

I'm using docker-compose for my rails app.

I recently pulled in updates to my master branch that updated the rails version to 5.2.3 -- and I ran bundle install via docker-compose:

`docker-compose run web bundle install`

Seemed like it ran fine, but then when I try to run rspec I get this error:

```
Could not find activesupport-5.2.3 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I try to run `bundle update activesupport` - and get this:

```
Bundler attempted to update activesupport but its version stayed the same
Bundle updated!
```

So I try to install the gem manually:

```
docker-compose run web gem install activesupport
Fetching activesupport-5.2.3.gem
Successfully installed activesupport-5.2.3
1 gem installed
```

Then I try to run rspec again, and same thing:

```
$ docker-compose run web bin/rspec ./spec/some_spec.rb 
Could not find activesupport-5.2.3 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Is docker-compose not picking up on the gem/bundler changes? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you add your `Dockerfile` and your `docker-compose.yml` to the question?  When you say “run rspec”, which command exactly are you running?

Comment: You can see in my description above that I am running it via `docker-compose run web bin/rspec ./spec/some_spec.rb `

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`docker-compose run` creates a new container each time it is invoked, your changes do not persist.

If you want your changes to persist, use `docker-compose exec`, which runs your command in the running container.

Answer (score 9):

Each `docker-compose run` is starting a new container.
Run it twice, and then run `docker ps -a` and you will see two Exited containers.

You need to run your `bundle install` as part of your image build process, inside your `Dockerfile`.

As a side note tip, it is common practice to first copy the `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` files only, run `bundle install`, and only then copy the entire app. This way you create two separate layers, and avoid reinstalling all the gems when the application files change.

Here is a `Dockerfile` for reference.

```
FROM ruby:2.5.3

WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT

# ... more custom stuff here ...

# Pre-install gems
COPY Gemfile* ./
RUN gem install bundler && bundle install --jobs=3 --retry=3 

# Copy app files
COPY . .
RUN chmod -R 755 $RAILS_ROOT/bin

# Run server
EXPOSE 3000
CMD bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
```